# How to open Drop Down only if in input entered required keyword?

Tags: reactjs

*How can i change my code that the drop-down list is shown only if a keyword is entered in the line.*

const styles = theme => ({
      container: {
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap"
      },
      textField: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
      },
      dense: {
        marginTop: 16
      },
      menu: {
        width: 200
      }
    });

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: "" };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="Dense"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.text}
          variant="outlined"
        />
        if () <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <button>Add {this.state.items.length}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.text.length) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: this.state.text,
      id: Date.now()
    };
    this.setState(state => ({
      items: state.items.concat(newItem),
      text: ""
    }));
  }
}

class Search extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>)}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'only if a keyword is entered in the line' ?

Comment: @viciousP let say if we entered `show` only in that time it will show dropDown

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by adding a checker, something like:

```
...
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TextField
          label="Dense"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.text}
          variant="outlined"
        />

         {this.state.text.includes('whatever word you want') && <TodoList items={this.state.items} />}
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <button>Add {this.state.items.length}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```